# It's very cold here

Tags: usage

In the following sentence

> It's very cold here I should have brought my woolen clothes but I didn't.

I think it should be

> It's very cold here I should have brought my woolen clothes but I haven't.

Because the sentence is in the present tense.

Comment: The first sentence is much more natural. (The second is awkward.) Both, however, are missing a conjunction between the two independent clauses (after *here*)—or a semicolon or period.

Answer (score 1):

You should split this into two sentences

> It's very cold here. I should have brought my woolen clothes but I didn't.

or add a semicolon.

> It's very cold here; I should have brought my woolen clothes but I didn't.

This is quite correct, and I prefer it to "... but I haven't". Both are correct English, there is no requirement for the tense in two coordinated clauses to be the same. And formally the first clause uses the past tense form "should".

The final clause refers to a past action, and either "I didn't (bring my woolen clothes)" or "I haven't (brought my woolen clothes)" could be correct, with very little difference in meaning.

You could also use a semicolon instead of full stop, to show that the first sentence and the second are linked.  Note also that "woolen" is the American spelling; "woollen" is British.

Answer (score 1):

I find *but I didn't* more natural.

I think you are making the assumption that *should have brought* is perfect, and so the negation should also be perfect (and use *have* rather than *did*).

This seems plausible, but is wrong. In the infinitive, *have brought* is the only way to form a past infinitive, and is not specifically perfect - it could be, but it doesn't have to be. (eg *I should have gone to see him last week* is not perfect: it corresponds more naturally to *I went to see him last week* than to the rather odd *I've been to see him last week*.).

So you can negate the *should have brought* with either *I didn't (bring iy)* or *I haven't (brought iy)*.